# program not starting on login as it requires UAC prompt

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have a program that requires administrative privileges to run (i.e. the UAC prompts when it starts)

Can i have this program run at start-up?  its in the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`  but fails to start when i log in.

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like to keep UAC on your current settings, you can have Task Scheduler run it for you on startup, with higher priviledges.

- First, remove the current startup entries for the program. [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) can help you with this.
- In Task Scheduler, set the **action** as the program you want to run, and have it run **when you log on**. Then in the **General** tab of your task, check **Run with highest priviledges** as shown here:

[image]

Complete guide [found here](http://slickdeals.net/forums/showthread.php?sduid=0&p=6509411) (it is for Vista, but 7's task scheduling is almost identical).

Comment: One note I'd like to add. Some programs, unless they're run as part of login won't correctly attach to the existing explorer.exe (they're run from taskhost.exe). This means if they rely upon the explorer to display a taskbar icon in the notification area, they won't. You can get around this by enabling `Allow task to be run on demand` and use `schtasks /run /tn 'Task Name'`

Comment: Thanx, using the task scheduler was the only way i was about to get around the UAC prompts